# Autocorrelation function $R_{yy}(t_1,t_2)$?

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, random-process

If $x(t)$ is a zero mean stationary Gaussian process and if $y(t)=x^2(t)$,then $\{y(t)\}$ is called a square law detector process. Now i want to find autocorrelation function $R_{yy}(t_1,t_2)$,that is 
$$R_{yy}(t_1,t_2)=E({y(t_1)y(t_2)})$$
$$=E(x^2(t_1)x^2(t_2))$$
Now after this step every books give the result like this

> $$R_{yy}(t_1,t_2)=E({x^2(t_1)})E({x^2(t_2)})+2E^2({x(t_2)}X
> (t_2))$$

But i don't know how this derivation came. Can anyone help me here please?

Comment: Could you cite a few books where the result is stated? I am not sure that you have transcribed it correctly,

Comment: @DilipSarwate this book  sir, page no 359 https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Probability_Statistics_and_Random_Proces.html?id=quctsgjLbJoC&redir_esc=y

Comment: @DilipSarwate  here also  https://books.google.co.in/books?id=W83qPDq4E8gC&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=the+input+to+a+diode+with+a+transfer+characteristics+y%3Dx%5E2&source=bl&ots=vqEZQnFlXw&sig=Eazlh-uaLRZA5TG7CnE4bertALM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif1_uVps3WAhUfTo8KHQ1VBzEQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=the%20input%20to%20a%20diode%20with%20a%20transfer%20characteristics%20y%3Dx%5E2&f=false

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sir can you help with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sigma^2$ denote the common variance of the random variables comprising the zero-mean stationary Gaussian process $\{X(t)\}$. We want to find
$$R_{Y}(t,s) = E[Y(t)Y(s)] = E\big[(X(t))^2(X(s))^2\big].$$
Now,
*given that* $X(t)=x$, 
\begin{align}
E\big[(X(t))^2(X(s))^2\mid X(t)=x\big] &=
E\big[x^2(X(s))^2\mid X(t)=x\big]\\
&= x^2E\big[(X(s))^2\mid X(t)=x\big]
\end{align}
where we know (since $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ are jointly Gaussian random variables with covariance $R_X(t-s)$ and correlation coefficient $\rho = \sigma^{-2}R_X(t-s)$) that the *conditional*
distribution of $X(s)$ given that $X(t) = x$ is a Gaussian distribution
with mean $\rho x$ and variance $\sigma^2(1-\rho^2)$. It follows that
\begin{align}
E\big[(X(t))^2(X(s))^2\mid X(t)=x\big] &= x^2E\big[(X(s))^2\mid X(t)=x\big]\\
&= x^2 \left(\sigma^2(1-\rho^2) + \rho^2x^2\right).\end{align}
Hence, the *random variable* $E\big[(X(t))^2(X(s))^2\mid X(t)]$
equals $(X(t))^2 \left( \sigma^2(1-\rho^2) + \rho^2(X(t))^2\right)$ and the law of iterated expectation gives

\begin{align}
E\big[(X(t))^2(X(s))^2\big]&=E\bigr[E\big[(X(t))^2(X(s))^2\mid X(t)\big]\bigr]\\
&= E\big[(X(t))^2\left(\sigma^2(1-\rho^2) + \rho^2(X(t))^2\right)\big]\\
&= \sigma^2(1-\rho^2)E[(X(t))^2] + \rho^2 E[(X(t))^4]\\
&= \sigma^4\left((1 - \rho^2) + 3\rho^2\right)\\
&= \sigma^4\left(1 + 2\rho^2\right)\\
&= (\sigma^2)^2 + 2 (\rho\sigma^2)^2\\
&= \left(R_X(0)\right)^2 + 2 \left(R_X(t-s)\right)^2\\
&= E[(X(t))^2]E[(X(s))^2] + 2\left(E[X(t)X(s)]\right)^2.
\end{align}
This differs in subtle ways (not just the use of $t$ and $s$ in place of $t_1$ and $t_2$) from what the OP insists is the right answer as stated in several books that he claims to have read, which answer he has faithfully transcribed into his question above.

Answer (score 0):

$Cov(y(t1),y(t2)) = E(y(t1)y(t2)) - E(y(t1))E(y(t2))$.

So, this means that

$ Cov(x^2(t1)x^2(t2)) = E(x^2(t1)x^2(t2)) - E(x1^2(t1))E(x2^2(t2))$

Now move the last term on the RHS over to the LHS which gives:

$E(x^2(t1)x^2(t2)) = Cov(x^2(t1)x^2(t2)) +  E(x^2(t1))E(x^2(t2))$.

So it comes down to sowing that  $Cov(x^2(t1)x^2(t2)) = $ something. But the something can't be what you have in your question. I think you have a typo in the last term of the expression for $R_{yy}(t_{1},t_{2})$. Even then, I'm not sure if it can be easily shown that they ( the something and Cov) are equal but atleast you'll have the right starting point. Good luck.

Comment: the link below probably contains the answer but as I said earlier, it's best to know the target first. http://www.arcetri.astro.it/~mosca/radioastronomy/corso/node34.html